# After a long sleep, my MacBook Pro seems always log me out

Tags: sleep-wake, macos

Got a new MBP Retina Display May 2015 15'' model.
It is upgraded to OS X El Capitan.

Whenever I put the MBP into sleep for a little bit long ( like 1 day ), when I come back, wake it up and  enter my password to get back to my screens, the applications all seems try to restart and lose the status. 
Note in the System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Advanced... the log out due to X minutes of inactivity is unchecked.

I am totally confused and this is very inconvenient.